# Needs to add anchor tag in featured image to open in new tab

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to add target="_blank" attribute in the code snippet so that when someone clicks on the post's featured image it opens in new tab. Following is the code

```
<?php 
                        $content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', "", $content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;

                        ?>
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnailnew2'); } ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'parabola' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-content --> 
                        <?php }  

            endif; 
         cryout_post_after_content_hook();  ?>
```

I tested for hours and realise that everything boils down to this line of code

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnailnew2'); } ?>
```

But if I try to make changes to it it results in error, I am not a WordPress developer but I can read codes. 
This is the changes made by me inside the code mentioned above.

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>    
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail

('thumbnailnew2'); ?></a>
```

Thank you for your support

Edit#1
code after suggestion from Jack

```
<?php 
                        $content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', "", $content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;

                        ?>
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>    
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnailnew2'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"/></a>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'parabola' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-content --> 
                        <?php }  

            endif; 
         cryout_post_after_content_hook();  ?>

    </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Edit#2 Full code with updated code provided by Jack

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * @package Cryout Creations
 * @subpackage Parabola
 * @since Parabola 1.0
 */

$options= parabola_get_theme_options();
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
     ${"$key"} = $value ;
} 

?><?php cryout_before_article_hook(); ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <?php parabola_comments_on(); ?>
        <header class="entry-header demo">          
            <h2 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'parabola' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
            <?php cryout_post_title_hook(); 
            ?><?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php parabola_posted_on(); 
                    cryout_post_meta_hook();  ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            <?php endif; ?>


        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
            <?php cryout_post_before_content_hook(); ?>  
            <?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() || is_page() ) : // Display excerpts for archives, search and page templates ?>

                        <?php if ($parabola_excerptarchive != "Full Post" ){ ?>
                        <div class="entry-summary">
                        <?php parabola_set_featured_thumb(); ?>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="entry-content demo111">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'parabola' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-content --> 
                        <?php }   ?>

        <?php else : 
                if (is_sticky() && $parabola_excerptsticky == "Full Post")  $sticky_test=1; else $sticky_test=0;
                if ($parabola_excerpthome != "Full Post" && $sticky_test==0){ ?>


                        <div class="entry-summary">
                        <?php parabola_set_featured_thumb(); ?>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="entry-content demo2222">

                        <?php 
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', "", $content);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    echo $content;
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>    
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnailnew2'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"/></a>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'parabola' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-content --> 
                        <?php }
    cryout_post_after_content_hook(); ?>

    </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->


<?php cryout_after_article_hook(); ?>
```

Edit#Final Resolved after suggestion from Samuel

> this code should work just fine it is just that you're missing a } and
>   endif; in the footer of your code, e.g
>   cryout_post_after_content_hook(); } endif; ?> (line:71)

issue resolved after suggestion from Samuel and amazing efforts by Jack Johansson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail()` will return a full link to your image. Instead, use `the_post_thumbnail_url();` to only fetch the URL:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>    
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnailnew2'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"/></a>
```

This will serve you nicely. And don't forget the semicolons, too.

**Update 1**

You have an unnecessary `endif;` causing syntax error. replace your entire code with the following:

```
<?php 
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', "", $content);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    echo $content;
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>    
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnailnew2'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"/></a>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'parabola' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-content --> 
                        <?php }
    cryout_post_after_content_hook(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank for help but I am getting same error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'  website www. barkadeh. com

Comment: Can you please update the question with the **final** code you are using? It seems like you have an unnecessary `endif` and `}` in your code, causing syntax error.

Comment: updated the question, please have a look under Edit#1

Comment: Updated the answer. Please replace the PHP code in your content with the updated in the answer.

Comment: same issue, I am now adding full php code so that it become easier, thank you for your help

Comment: I validated the code before updating the question, didn't find any error. You are welcome.

Comment: @JamesMascarenhas this code should work just fine it is just that you're missing a `}` and `endif;` in the footer of your code, e.g `cryout_post_after_content_hook(); } endif; ?>` (line:71)

Comment: Thank you @SamuelElh it is working now, Thank you again Jack Johansson for giving your time and efforts.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't have the full code and didn't notice there is an `if()` in the missing section of the code. Glad it helped you.